# What ever happened to the Chromating capability/feature of Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome

What ever happened to the [Chromoting capability](http://www.allgeek.tv/2011/02/18/remotely-control-chrome-chromoting/) (allowing you to remotely access an app on a Windows/Mac computer) of Google Chrome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This blog says](http://www.conceivablytech.com/7505/products/google-removes-integrated-remoting-form-chrome) that code for the feature was removed earlier this year, with the functionality supposedly relegated to an Extension. (However, I've been unable to find any such extension, so I'm pretty sure it doesn't exist.)

Comment: Now in beta testing: http://lifehacker.com/5848179/chrome-remote-desktop-controls-other-computers-from-a-chrome-tab